# Bootstrap 5 - How to display tab content to always display to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5, I am able to display tab content that always displays (no matter which tab the user is in):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Tabs navs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabNavs01">
  <li class="nav-item"><a id="t-customer" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#tabcustomer">customer</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a id="t-position" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#tabposition">position</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tabs content -->
<div class="tab-content col-md-7 flex-nowrap" id="tabCont01">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabcustomer">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <h2>ENTER:&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtcustomer" placeholder="customer" class="form-control add-main" onclick="validatecustomer();">
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtcomputer" placeholder="computer" class="form-control add-computer" onclick="validatecustomer();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabposition">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <h2>ENTER:&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtposition" placeholder="position" class="form-control position-box" onclick="searchByposition();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><strong>Testing</strong></label>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This produces the area "Testing" that appears in both tabs as desired:

[image]

My question is how can I get this "Testing" text to appear to the right of both tabs?  I am trying to get it to this location inside the "white" area and aligned with the words "ENTER" as seen here:

[image]

### Update

Thank you Kameron, your solution below worked nice. If I wanted to add some svg in this area, would that be possible such as this Facebook/Twitter images:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **"Testing"** next to the `tab-content` you have to use `.d-flex` on the `.tab-pane` parent. You already had `.flex-nowrap`, but it is invalid without having `.d-flex` or another `flex` class.

Next, you can just use Bootstraps `.flex-grow-1` class on the first and second child to `.tab-content`.

> Use `.flex-grow-*` utilities to toggle a flex item’s ability to grow to fill available space.
>
> - [Flex · Bootstrap v5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink)

You can then configure out your `widths` etc, but as long as you have `d-flex` on the parent with `.flex-nowrap` you will always have your desired **"Testing"** div next to each `.tab-pane`.

```css
/* for SVG demo only */

svg[aria-label="Facebook"] {
  background: #3b5998;
}

svg[aria-label="Twitter"] {
  background: #55acee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Tabs navs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs align-items-center" id="tabNavs01">
  <li class="nav-item"><a id="t-customer" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#tabcustomer">customer</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a id="t-position" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#tabposition">position</a></li>
  <li class="svgs ms-auto me-2">
    <svg role="img" aria-label="Facebook" width="30" height="30">
      <title>Facebook</title>
    </svg>
    <svg role="img" aria-label="Twitter" width="30" height="30">
      <title>Twitter</title>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tabs content -->
<div class="tab-content d-flex col-md-7 flex-nowrap align-items-center" id="tabCont01">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active flex-grow-1" id="tabcustomer">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <h2 class="me-2">ENTER:</h2>
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtcustomer" placeholder="customer" class="form-control add-main" onclick="validatecustomer();">
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtcomputer" placeholder="computer" class="form-control add-computer" onclick="validatecustomer();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade flex-grow-1" id="tabposition">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <h2 class="me-2">ENTER:</h2>
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtposition" placeholder="position" class="form-control position-box" onclick="searchByposition();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ms-2">
    <label><strong>Testing</strong></label>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Kameron, your solution below worked nice. I awarded you the bounty. If I wanted to add some svg in this area, would that be possible such as this facebook/twitter images.  See example I added above.  Thank you again.

Comment: @RobertSmith No problem, Robert. Your request is certainly possible. What I would do is create a new `li` under `ul.nav-tabs` and call it something like `.sgvs`. Then, you can nest your SVGS (img, icon, etc.)  in this new `li` and use the `ms-auto` class on it. `.ms-auto` is Bootstraps class equivalent to `margin-left: auto;` The SVGS I used are for demonstration purposes. See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

To display tab content that always shows regardless of which tab the user is currently in using Bootstrap 5, you can add the "show active" classes to the content element of the first tab. This will ensure that the content is visible by default and will not be hidden when switching between tabs.

Comment: Thank you Abdul for your response.  Please take a look at the second image above.  What I am attempting to do is to have the "Testing" words always appear to the right of the textbox.  Currently it places the "Testing" text on the next line and I do not want it to be on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I added two changes to achieve that based on your structure

1. add `d-flex` class to `.tab-content`
2. add following css `.tab-pane { flex-grow: 1; }`

Have a look on the snippet result.

```css
.tab-pane {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabNavs01">
  <li class="nav-item"><a id="t-customer" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#tabcustomer">customer</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a id="t-position" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#tabposition">position</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tabs content -->
<div class="tab-content col-md-7 d-flex flex-nowrap" id="tabCont01">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabcustomer">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <h2>ENTER:&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtcustomer" placeholder="customer" class="form-control add-main" onclick="validatecustomer();">
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtcomputer" placeholder="computer" class="form-control add-computer" onclick="validatecustomer();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabposition">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <h2>ENTER:&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
      <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txtposition" placeholder="position" class="form-control position-box" onclick="searchByposition();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><strong>Testing</strong></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To align **Testing** vertically centered further, you can just add `d-flex align-items-center` to its `<div>` element container. `<div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <label><strong>Testing</strong></label> </div>`

Comment: Why not just use Bootstraps `.flex-grow-1` class instead of using unnecessary custom CSS??

Comment: yes, you can use `.flex-grow-1` instead. I didn't use it because I wannt style all `.tab-pane` at once.